# Which place(s) are the first to cross into New Year?

Tags: destinations, events, geography

Say I wanted to be the first to celebrate the New Year: what place or places are the first to cross the into the New Year and how do I get there? I think I remember this may be some South Pacific island or in Australia but not sure.

Comment: For the change of millennium some of the tiny pacific countries tried and maybe succeeded to get the date line rearranged so they could be the first!

Comment: Should point out that the International Date Line doesn't actually move, so no countries 'cross' it as such.  However it's now 2012 in New Zealand, party on!

Comment: Are you asking in which places it reaches midnight first? Or are you asking for travel routes that some how cross the international date line? Your question is worded in a confusing way, that makes it sound like either places, or the international date line, move. Of course places are stationary; and so is the international date line.

Comment: I don't know which places were the first to cross the date line, but Samoa and Tokelau are the most recent places to do so, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/December_2011#2011_December_29)!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can see this in the [Wikipedia list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zones_by_UTC_offset) or on any map with the [International Date Line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:International_Date_Line.png). The first places to see a new day are:

- The [Line Islands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_Islands), more precisely the part that belongs to [Kiribati](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiribati) (formerly known as the Gilbert Islands). The Line Islands are in the UTC+14 timezone, and the rest of the country is in UTC+13. This has been the case since 1995; before that, the country straddled the date line. The Line Islands saw some first-to-new-millennium tourism in 2000.
- [Samoa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samoa) (an independent country) and [Tokelau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokelau) (a dependency of New Zealand), since 2012. Together with Samoa, [Tokelau skipped 2011-12-30](http://www.tokelau.org.nz/site/tokelau/files//Press%20Release%2028122011%20.pdf) to move from the western hemisphere to the eastern hemisphere, in order to match weekdays with the other countries in Oceania. Tokelau moved from UTC-10 to UTC+14. Samoa moved from UTC-11 to UTC+13 and introduced daylight savings time at that point, so on the new year (which falls during the summer) it is at UTC+14.
- [Tonga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonga), since 2017. The base timezone of Tonga is UTC+13, but Tonga [introduced DST in 2016](http://matangitonga.to/2016/10/27/summer-daylight-saving-moves-tonga-14-hours-ahead-utc).

And if you want to be the last to cross the line, there are formally a few places at UTC-12, but they are uninhabited [US Minor Outlying Islands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Minor_Outlying_Islands). In UTC-11 are more US Minor Outlying Islands, [American Samoa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Samoa) and the New Zealand dependency of [Niue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niue) (as long as it doesn't follow Tokelau's example).

Answer (score 6):

Of the bigger countries, New Zealand is the first to celebrate New Year. But there are a few island territories that are one hour ahead, namely [Samoa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samoa) and [Tokelau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokelau)

timeanddate.com has a [countdown page to New Years](http://www.timeanddate.com/counters/multicountdown.html)